# XP-Styles not working for ListView or ComboBox in Windows XP

Tags: winapi, windows-7, windows-xp

I am using a Manifest for XP Styles, so all my controls are using the new look. However if I run my program in Windows XP then my ListView controls are displaying with the old style flat headers. Also the HDS_NOSIZING style is not working for the headers. This seems to imply that XP is using the old Common Controls 5.0 version of the listview instead of 6.0.

I'm very confused about this whole thing. I read that Common Controls 6.00 ships with XP, so why can't I use the latest ListView with XP?

I read on another page that XP-Styles only work in XP for Common Controls 5.0 ListViews but not for 6.0. So if it is indeed using 5.0, then shouldn't it apply the new XP-Styles to listviews anyway?

Is it actually possible to use the Common Controls 6.0 version of some controls and the 5.0 version of others?

Also one other thing. In XP my ComboBox Drop-down lists appear like regular Combo boxes instead of like Buttons as they do in Win7. Is this normal?

Thanks for your help as I find this whole Common Controls 6.0 + XP Styles concept very confusing.

Comment: What language? Are your calling `InitCommonControls()`?

Comment: The "it only works on the v5 common controls" is a VB6 thing. The VB common controls 6 don't use the standard win32 controls and so won't have the theme support, the v5 one DO use the standard win32 controls and so will use whichever version is specified in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You are hoping to see Windows 7 styles back on Windows XP.  That's not going to work.  XP *will* show flat headers, HDS_NOSIZING is only supported in Vista and up.  Similarly, combo boxes with the CBS_DROPDOWNLIST only appear as buttons in Vista and up.

In all likelihood, your program is working exactly as it should and is displaying proper XP styles.  You can double-check with a debugger.  Debug + Windows + Modules and look at the version number of the loaded comctl32.dll